# Why doesn't my binary search implementation find the last element?

Tags: c, arrays, binary-search

I have implemented a beginner recursive version of binary search in C. However, it doesn't seem to work when the element to be found is in the last position of the array. Is there any way to fix this without changing the prototype of the function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int search(int value, int values[], int n);

int main() {
    int a[] = { 26, 27, 28 };

    if (search(28, a, 3) == 0)
        printf("Found.\n");
    else
        printf("Not found.\n");
}

int search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) 
        return 1;

    if (value < values[n/2])
        // Search the left half
        return search(value, values, n/2);
    else if (value > values[n/2])
        // Search the right half, excluding the middle term
        return search(value, values + n/2 + 1, n/2 - 1);
    else 
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I just ran your code; it works fine? Can you clarify your error, your reproducible steps?

Comment: Why are you returning `0` if the `value == values[n/2]` ? Shouldn't you return `n/2` ? And the `return 1` line is useless.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think zero is correct, it returns 0 or 1 to indicate whether a value was found, 0 being true.

Comment: on the array {26, 27, 28} I seem to get a wrong answer.

Comment: @Miket25 Oh.. I thought it is supposed to return the index.

Comment: So it works when there is an even number of items to search but not when there is an uneven number... that should tell you that there is something wrong with the mathematics here

Comment: what do you think what `n/2 - 1` will be if N is 3 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a recursive binary search in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803940/writing-a-recursive-binary-search-in-c)

Comment: `n/2 - 1` --> `n - n/2 - 1`

Comment: Learn how to use the **debugger.** – You have a concrete case where your function fails, that is great. Now single-step through the code and check where the flow is not as you would expect it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you, this answer came most intuitively to me. Although simply "n/2" is correct, it specifies the size of the current slice to be searched, and when n is even the last step will come down to the size being 2, when it is in fact 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `search` function is incorrect:

- The slice size you pass when you recurse on the right part is computed incorrectly: it should be `n - n/2 - 1` instead of `n/2 - 1`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int search(int value, int values[], int n);

int main(void) {
    int a[] = { 26, 27, 28 };

    if (search(28, a, 3) == 0)
        printf("Found.\n");
    else
        printf("Not found.\n");

    return 0;
}

int search(int value, int values[], int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        int mid = n / 2;
        if (value < values[mid]) {
            // Search the left half
            return search(value, values, mid);
        } else
        if (value > values[mid]) {
            // Search the right half, excluding the middle term
            return search(value, values + mid + 1, n - mid - 1);
        } else {
            // Found the value
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here is a simpler iterative version:

```
int search(int value, int values[], int n) {
    while (n > 0) {
        int mid = n / 2;
        if (value < values[mid]) {
            // Search the left half
            n = mid;
        } else
        if (value > values[mid]) {
            // Search the right half, excluding the middle term
            values += mid + 1;
            n -= mid + 1;
        } else {
            // Found the value
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be your return statement in your else if clause. The length of the array `n` should be `n-n/2-1` and not `n/2-1` or else the last element will be clipped off. You can see this to be more prevalent as the length of the array increases and as you're searching for elements coming from the right side.

```
return search(value, values + n/2 + 1, n - n/2 - 1);
```

**Note:**
As chqrlie pointed out

Comment: @chqrlie That's a good point and an important one. Though I'll leave that to the discretion of the OP, being that the main concern seemed to be the mathematical logic.

Comment: @chqrlie Actually, that would resolve the out-of-bounds issue, nice catch.